# Assign values from vector to dynamic array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dynamic

I have a vector of vertices of a line called `lineVertices` and I am going to pass this data to draw an OpenGL shape, so this vector must be in the form of an array, I'm assuming. I've tried the following code:

```
float* lineArray = new float[lineVertices.size()]();

for (unsigned i = 0; i < lineVertices.size(); i++) {
    lineArray[i] = lineVertices.at(i);
}
```

However, it appears that the each element of the vector is getting assigned to the first element of the array only. Even though the `lineArray` identifier is a pointer to the first element, is there another way to access the different elements of the dynamic array?

If it helps, when I am debugging, it says that the size of `lineArray` is always 1, although `lineVertices'` size is clearly greater than 1.

I have also tried the code below, but this also does not work.

```
float* lineArray = &lineVertices[0];
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Here's some help: read the help center article about how to assemble a [mcve] and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What specific OpenGL function are you passing your vector/array to? How are you currently calling it?

Comment: *so this vector must be in the form of an array* -- Huh??  You do know that a `vector` has the `array` you're looking for by just calling the `vector::data()` function?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Clearly not, that's why they're asking the question... Why don't you give an answer to explain the misunderstanding instead of not-so-subtly insulting the OP? I see way too many of your type of comments on SO. [Be nice.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: The code clearly creates the float array using `new[]` by using the number of entries in the vector, and then sets each entry in the loop (which you could have used `std::copy` BTW).  Thus I see nothing wrong with this code (except that none of this needs to be done due to a vector having the `vector::data()`  function to get the array).  I think you're misinterpreting what the debugger is showing you.

Comment: The problem is in code you didn't post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `std::vector` directly to OpenGL functions taking a pointer to an array. Just use the [`::data()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) member function. Example:

```
std::vector<float> vec = ...;
glVertex2fv(vec.data()); // only uses the first two elements
```

OpenGL functions like this take a pointer to one or more elements. This doesn't have to be a raw array created with `new`; it just has to be a pointer to a consecutive list of elements. Use `vector.data()` to get a pointer to a `std::vector`'s contents (first element).

If you really want to create a new array with manual memory management, you can do this (same effect as the code you posted):

```
float* arr = new float[vec.size()]; // NO () - not a constructor, but operator new[]
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    arr[i] = vec[i];
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use glVertex2fv(), which I believe only takes a pointer to an array. How would I make this happen?

Comment: @qxz -- `// NO () - not a constructor, but operator new[]`  -- It is perfectly valid to add parentheses to the usage of `new[]`.  All it does is zero-initialize the elements.

Comment: The part of the answer with `new[]` is really no different than the OP's attempt in terms of the final result.  The only difference being is that the OP's attempt initializes the data using `()` and calls `at()` in the loop.